# Same random values when two random() called?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Have a Javascript class which creates custom shapes:

```js
let sq = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  let rand_num = random(0,10);
  for (let i = 0; i < rand_num; i++) {
    sq[i] = new class(value);
  }
  noStroke();
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  let rand_num = random(0,10);
  for (let i = 0; i < rand_num; i++) {
    sq[i].a_custom_shape();
  }
}
```

However the problem is that it occasionally will display error message stating the method `a_custom_shape` in draw function is not defined. Probably due to having difference random values inside the `sq` array as having two `rand_num`. So whether there are any ways to make the two random functions having same result values?

Comment: Why is there "randomness" in `draw()`? Should all elements from `sq` be drawn, or just a random selection of it?

Comment: You could loop on the length of sq, inside your draw function, to be sure you're not trying to get something outside of the array

Comment: randomness is for making it to draw shapes at random amount every time. The problem is it generates random values separately so it probably caused error as having difference values in the same array.

Comment: _"...at random amount every time"_ - Hence the `random()` call in `setup()`. But why the `random()` call in `draw()`? If all elements from `sq` should be drawn, then do as Julien suggested and loop from `i = 0` to `i <= sq.length` and get rid of the `random()` part in `draw()`

Comment: `i < rand_num` should be `i < sq.length`

Comment: Ah yep. "i < sq.length" worked thanks.